# Https requests "invalid request (unsupported ssl request)"

Tags: laravel, ssl, https, laravel-5.1

I'm having problems with Https requests in Laravel 5.1

I created a Middleware like this:

```
    <?php

namespace Subway\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use App;
use Redirect;

class UseSSL
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
          if (!$request->secure() && env('APP_ENV') === 'local')
          {
              return redirect()->secure($request->getRequestUri());
          }
          return $next($request);
    }
}
```

and my routes are like this:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'use.ssl'], function () {
// All other routes here
});
```

I registered the middleware in kernel.php

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
      'use.ssl' => \Subway\Http\Middleware\UseSSL::class,
    ];
```

When trying to get to any url, the page doesn't load and the terminal is returning this error:

```
[Thu Nov 12 11:09:30 2015] ::1:50728 Invalid request (Unsupported SSL request)
```

What's the problem with this?

Comment: From your description I assume you're using `php artisan serve` to serve the application. That makes use of [PHP's built-in web server](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php), which as the warning a the top of the docs page states: **"It is not intended to be a full-featured web server."**. One of the missing features is SSL support. You need to setup your secure dev environment using a more robust server that can handle secure connections, such as _nginx_ or _Apache_.

Answer (score 0):

Try to past this lines of code:

```php
    public function boot()
    {
        if (!$this->app->isLocal()) {
            $this->app['request']->server->set('HTTPS', true);
        }
    }
```

into your `app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php` file

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your Api Call has the same protocol as the server you are creating. for example, [const String baseURL = "http://192.168.0.104:8000/api";]
when your Server is [http://192.168.0.104:8000]. both are HTTP and not HTTPS